# How to calculate the angle of rotation of a 2D car so that it touches the road

Tags: geometry

Here's a problem that I am having, let's say we have a 2D car (oversimplified in this example), which has two wheels that should be touching the ground, wheels have different radii. We have a road, assumed to be horizontal for now. It is trivial to figure out when one wheel touches the ground, so I start with that.

Now I want to figure out the angle , which would rotate the car around the center of the touching wheel in such a way as to have the car touching the road with the second wheel as well.

[image]

It is trivial to find the height that the second wheel should fall in the `y` direction, that is `h`. The base of the car is known, that is `b`. I understand that once I find `dx` I can find . But I am completely stuck.

I understand that we have several angles with the same magnitude, and I do understand that it is possible to draw another right triangle with the sides `h`, (`b`-`dx`) with `b` as hypotenuse. But everything I am trying gets me to something that still has unknown variables.

I would really like to know the way to calculate .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

According to the diagram

$$\sin\theta = \frac hb\hspace{1cm}\implies\hspace{1cm} \theta = \arcsin\frac hb$$

Comment: No, sorry. sin(theta) is definitely not h/b, it is sin (h/(b-dx))

Comment: @v010dya - do you see any problem in the diagram?

Comment: I got confused a bit, i see where i made a mistake and your answer is correct.